# AWS Glue error when reading from Data Catalog with Iceberg (S3Exception: Access Denied)

Tags: aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I had this problem when trying to read from Glue Data Catalog. The complete exception was `software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Access Denied`

I checked my IAM permission but realized that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by specifying the **Glue Database URI location** of the Database I was writing to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).